# Pivot-table-esque result using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to do this in LINQ - I've been banging my head against this for a while now:

Source:

```
var selectedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var selectedMonth = selectedDate.Month;
var selectedYear = selectedDate.Year;

var data = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass { Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), Val1 = 1, Val2 = 2 },
    new MyClass { Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2), Val1 = 1, Val2 = 2 },
    new MyClass { Date = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1), Val1 = 1, Val2 = 2 }
};

Date       | Val1 | Val2
01/01/2013 | 1    | 2
02/01/2013 | 1    | 2
01/02/2013 | 1    | 2
```

Result (the sums of each `Val` vs the Date/Month/Year):

```
     | selectedDate | selectedMonth | selectedYear
Val1 | 1            | 2             | 3
Val2 | 2            | 4             | 6
```

Comment: What Linq provider, Linq-To-Objects, Linq-To-Sql,Linq-To-Entities,...? What is the input, what the desired output?

Comment: It's an enumerated list of classes. Sorry I'll update Q accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think LINQ is the solution, really. You can easily get a single pivoted "row", but you need to enumerate the sequence again to get the next one, which isn't very efficient (and doesn't work if the source is a "lazy" enumerable and you don't want to keep the whole sequence in memory).

I think the simplest, efficient solution is a standard `foreach`. You could translate this to LINQ using [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) if you had to, but it wouldn't be as straightforward:

```
        var val1 = new Result();
        var val2 = new Result();
        foreach (var item in data) {
            if (item.Date == selectedDate) {
                val1.Date += item.Val1;
                val2.Date += item.Val2;
            }
            if (item.Date.Month == selectedMonth) {
                val1.Month += item.Val1;
                val2.Month += item.Val2;
            }
            if (item.Date.Year == selectedYear) {
                val1.Year += item.Val1;
                val2.Year += item.Val2;
            }
        }
```

There are probably ways this could be made more dynamic, but that's a whole other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new List<Result>{
    new Result{
      Val = "Val1",
      Date = data.Sum(e => e.Val1 * (e.Date == selectedDate ? 1 : 0)),
      Month = data.Sum(e => e.Val1 * (e.Date.Month == selectedMonth ? 1 : 0)),
      Year = data.Sum(e => e.Val1 * (e.Date.Year == selectedYear ? 1 : 0)),
    },
    new Result{
      Val = "Val2",
      Date = data.Sum(e => e.Val2 * (e.Date == selectedDate ? 1 : 0)),
      Month = data.Sum(e => e.Val2 * (e.Date.Month == selectedMonth ? 1 : 0)),
      Year = data.Sum(e => e.Val2 * (e.Date.Year == selectedYear ? 1 : 0)),
    }
};
```

---

With `Result`:

```
public class Result {
    public String Val { get; set; }
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Count(x => ...)` is a nicer alternative to `Sum(x => ... ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: True, but here we must multiply by `e.Val1`.

Comment: I missed that. Still, we could avoid it by using `Where(e => ...).Sum(e => e.Val1)`.

Comment: Use reflection to find all of the properties to make it dynamic.  Painful and bloated... but dynamic.